# (Unity android game) How to make the additional download for android games?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a storybook kind of app, when people bought extra story i need somehow to download the extra content as a additional download. can some one elaborate how can i do that from unity (cause i'm using unity to build the app). how to bundle the assets and how to make it as a extra download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a button that is greyed out for not containing the data.
That button contains a script checking if there is data at a location.

The user purchases the item and then starts the download. The data are stored at the location where the button will search for most likely at Application.persistentDataPath.

The actual data are stored on your server at a url. Most likely a secured url requiring a login system (could be Azure or AWS).

Next time the button is started it will look at the location and find the data. It is now active.

Downloading could be made easy with AssetBundle so you can download a whole scene into it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

Comment: Thanks !! it will be help full if you can guide me to a tutorial or some article shows how to do it..

Comment: The Unity doc on AssetBundle gives quite a lot of explanation already. I added the link